# How to install a vinyl fence gate on a pool deck?

Tags: fence, construction, carpentry, decking, gates

I am trying to install a vinyl fence between a deck and the pool in a backyard. The homeowner wants the fence (Wam Bam Vinyl Fence system) to run the width of the backyard until it gets to the deck steps and wants them wants the vinyl fence to attach to a vinyl gate that can be opened to allow people to access the pool.

[image: where fence will be between yard and pool]
[image: backyard deck and steps]

Since the steps down from the deck are essentially touching the house, I’m wondering if there is a way to attach the gate securely.  Assuming the gate’s hinge side can be on either side - how can I get anything securely attached to the house side of the steps that the gate can latch to or that the gate itself can be fixed to?

Comment: let me ge this straight, is it for that plastic picket fence in the photos?

Comment: As written this does not sound so much like DIY.

Comment: @Jasen No! Wam Bam vinyl fencing is 4x6 ft sections with a post - then they have a separate gate module that is 4x4 foot.